cmd command is not working in batch file but works in normal cmd
I am trying to create a batch setup file that reads pc's serial number and adds it to a text file. the issue is that the command to get the serial number is not working in the script but it works when I copy-paste it in cmd
the cmd code is:
@echo off
set CURRENT_DIR=%~dp0
@echo off
cd /d "%~dp0"
:: Check if running as administrator
net session >nul 2>&1
if %errorLevel% neq 0 (
    echo Running as administrator...
    powershell -Command "Start-Process '%0' -Verb RunAs"
    exit /b
)
echo.
echo Current Directory: %CD%
if not exist "%CURRENT_DIR%\Tracking" (
    mkdir "%CURRENT_DIR%\Tracking"
)
for /f "skip=1 tokens=2 delims=" %%a in ('wmic bios get serialnumber /value') do (
    set "TRACKID=%%a"
    goto :next
)
:next
echo %TRACKID% > "%CURRENT_DIR%\Tracking\track_id.txt"
echo Serial Number: %TRACKID%
pause

in tracking_id.txt, I find the wording "Echo is OFF" instead of serial number, but when I run command "wmic bios get serialnumber" in cmd, I get the serial number. What am I doing wrong?

hello your skip and delims are off
try this skip=2 tokens=2 delims==
skip is how many lines you are skipping,
tokens is the position of what you are taking and the delim is the delimeter in this case "="
it worked for me
